# Open New Form on button click, Close exisiting Form, VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, forms, vb6

Sorry for asking a really dumb question. I've been a vb6 programmer for years and I am just developing my first application in VS2010.

I'm trying to open a new form on a button click and close the current form.

In VB6 I would have used.

`Me.Close
Form.Show vbmodal`

I've googled for a solution and it tells me the code is basically the same

`form.show()
me.close`
However, when I click the button the program closes. If I take away `me.close`, the form shows.

I'm really confused.

Thanks

John

Comment: Project + Properties, change Shutdown mode to "When last form closes".  Look around a bit more, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the form that you are closing is the one that starts your application ('startup form'), then your application ends.

Try with

```
Me.Hide()
form.Show()
```

But you could also change the Property `Shutdown mode` for the project.
On the `Applications Tab` set the `Shutdown mode` to  `When the last form closes`.
Of course, in this case, the order of the commands should be

```
form.Show()
Me.Close()
```

Comment: That explains it. Me.hide works. Thanks

I'm assuming every form after that I can use me.close

Comment: Well, if you need to keep the login form around for the lifetime of your application (perhaps to show it again and request a relogin after an inactive timeout period) then you could use the Hide method, but if this is not the case then change the Shutdown mode and get rid of the login form

Answer (score 2):

Try with `Me.Hide()`  in place of `Me.Close().`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim f As New Form1
    f.Show()
```

Checked!! as you see I declare f as new Form1, here you have to change with your form name under form properties then the next line is to show the copy of f!